# Capture verbose output of powershell cmdlet running on a remote server

Tags: powershell

I am running a powershell cmdlet with -Verbose option , But i can't capture its output to a variable or script ?
I can see verbose logs on shell but can't redirect it. Can it be limited by the cmdlet itself or by the shell i am running it in ?
The shell is a restricted powershell i guess.
Although i can do it for any command that i write using say Write-verbose cmdlet .
Any pointers why this would happen ?
Please let me know if any other information is required.
How do i basically Capture verbose output of powershell cmdlet running on a remote server ?

[image]

Comment: `$outputWithVerbose = Command-Name -Verbose 4>&1`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Strangely i tried this, its not working .

Comment: @nhupesh - Works for me. Perhaps your command doesn't have verbose ouput. What are you using? Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: What does this return? `$test = Write-Verbose 'xyz' 4>&1; "$(get-date) - $($test)"`

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers $test is xyz  when i am executing this in my  powershell script. Though on shell if i just execute this command , it shows VERBOSE: xyz in value of $test and it prints "07/23/2020 19:33:17 - xyz"

Comment: The `$test` variable is a `VerboseRecord` object. That is why you see differences when showing it in a string as opposed to showing it in the shell. It did capture the message though. The message is `xyz`. The cyan and verbose is just pretty printing.

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers , But the problem is still not solved for cmdlet that i am running  , right ?